# Can I omit certain work experience while searching for jobs?

Tags: resume, job-search, work-experience

I have been working in a software product development company for the past seven years. And prior to that I had 9 months of experience in another company.

Now I am looking for a job, but my experience is too high (actually I haven't learnt as much as my work experience indicateds, and my salary is also very smaller than what's expected).

So can I omit my work experience with related technology on my resume? I am not going to hide everything. I plan on reducing my working experience to something like 5 years. Will it be accepted?

Comment: What kind of job are you seeking? Same field or type or is it different?

Comment: i have been working as product support with same technology(ASP.NET) only. Mostly doing routine job as well.

Comment: Related: [How should I explain being overqualified?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/40344) [Strategies for getting work experience to enter workforce when overqualified](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/100386) [Can I omit a degree and related work experience from my resume if I don't want to work in that area?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/18447)

Comment: Omitting the last 7 years of experience would be a bit much, lying about your dates of employment (to omit part of the job) or only including part of your time at the company (if you had different titles) would be worse.

Comment: What exactly are you planning to omit?

Comment: I am not going to omit as whole. I plan to reduce my working experience suppose for 7years i  plan to put related  experience is only 5 years . Will it be accepted.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Can I safely leave out portions of my employment history to showcase my last 'relevant experience?'](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80755/can-i-safely-leave-out-portions-of-my-employment-history-to-showcase-my-last-re)

Comment: @vela When the company goes to do a background check, they'll see that you worked there for 7 years and not 5 and wonder why you lied to them.

Comment: I meant to say i have worked with for 7 years but my related experience with the related technology could be 5 years is that ok.

Comment: Please [edit] updates or your replies to comments into the question itself.

Comment: Your resumé is your sales brochure.  It's up to you to use it to paint yourself in the best light possible.  You can omit anything you feel like omitting (be it positive or negative).  What you shouldn't do is say anything that is actually untrue.  If you do omit some experience, be prepared to explain why there's a gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So can I deduce my work experience with related technology on my resume.

Usually you want to **customize your resume according to the type of job you seek**. This means you include only the things you wish to show and also make each one stand out the way you think better.

If you want to apply for a position of, say a Python web developer job, then your resume should focus more on your experience and knowledge about that subject and focus less on other not-so related things (i.e. in this case, past experience on sales and marketing).

You can surely do whatever you want with your resume, but willingly omitting **too much** experience on a topic in your resume may not be so recommended. Your deception may become evident **if** they do some research on your profile, and that may compromise your application.

They may also become aware of that once/if you are hired and your overqualified skills start showing. You may decide to try hide those skills or deliberately work slowly, but I doubt if it is worth the effort.

In any case, I suggest you include *only related experience and refrain from including too much details* on them. This way they may consider you less overqualified and give you better chances. On interviews that follow you can **truthfully** (preferably) enhance or clarify any other details regarding the nature of your experience they may want to know.

**Edit:** You indicate now that you plan to leave out 2 years of experience. It is up to you to decide if that is "too much" to safely remove it. Personally, I would leave it untouched. I think it's safer to omit the 9 months on the other company than 2 years in the most recent one (more likely they will check you last job).

Answer (score 4):

> So can I omit my work experience with related technology on my resume?

Yes.

You can always choose to omit any work experience you choose from your resume.

If it leaves a gap, be prepared to explain what you did in that time frame. That said, omitting a 9 month job over 7 years ago is unlikely to attract any attention.

I'm not sure why this would make you look more favorable to an employer (I'd leave it in), but you can certainly omit it if you prefer.

Comment: Agree, a job so far in the past is unlikely to attract attention

Answer (score 1):

> So can I omit my work experience with related technology on my resume?

You can, but **I would not recommend doing so.**

Be **careful** if you choose to go the route of leaving an employer off your resume/application.  If your potential employer so desires, *they may run a background check* which might show the company your attempting to hide.  At that point your integrity has been compromised.  Then come the **uncomfortable questions as to why this information wasn't disclosed**, and it may come across that you are lying.

I suggest you **always be honest**, and have your resume be an true reflection of your work experience.  This way you can avoid any awkward conversations as to why you left out a certain employer.

Comment: FYI, OP has clarified that they want to reduce their experience at one company from 7 years to 5 years.